# Errno::ENOENT after problemless start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a problem, I hope you can help me: 
there is a site: sorsveto.hu (actually the problem is there, you can 
check it).

Few days ago we set it on production mode. 
It is running on an nginx with 3 thin clasters. Its stand up well without 
any problems. Two days later suddenly an error appeared:

```
Errno::ENOENT 
No such file or directory - /ror/sorsveto/sorsveto.hu/www/config/locales/en.yml 
Rails.root: /ror/sorsveto/sorsveto.hu/www
```

At the moment I can restart the application if I upload a file 
"restart" (without extension). Anyway if I restart the application the 
error is still there. 
And of course the `en.yml` file is there. 
I don't know why is this happens and even don't know how to solve it. 
I've seen some solutions about this error but mostly focused on win7 
setups and single gem updates. 
I hope you can tell me some useful handling.

Yours, 
Előd, Czakó

I add the list of gems I use:

```
GEM

  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.1)
      actionpack (= 3.0.1)
      mail (~> 2.2.5)
    actionpack (3.0.1)
      activemodel (= 3.0.1)
      activesupport (= 3.0.1)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.4.1)
      rack (~> 1.2.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.6.12)
      rack-test (~> 0.5.4)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activemodel (3.0.1)
      activesupport (= 3.0.1)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.4.1)
    activerecord (3.0.1)
      activemodel (= 3.0.1)
      activesupport (= 3.0.1)
      arel (~> 1.0.0)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activeresource (3.0.1)
      activemodel (= 3.0.1)
      activesupport (= 3.0.1)
    activesupport (3.0.1)
    arel (1.0.1)
      activesupport (~> 3.0.0)
    builder (2.1.2)
    erubis (2.6.6)
      abstract (>= 1.0.0)
    i18n (0.4.2)
    mail (2.2.9)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
      i18n (~> 0.4.1)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.16)
    mysql (2.8.1)
    mysql (2.8.1-x86-mingw32)
    polyglot (0.3.1)
    rack (1.2.1)
    rack-mount (0.6.13)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.5.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.0.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.0.1)
      actionpack (= 3.0.1)
      activerecord (= 3.0.1)
      activeresource (= 3.0.1)
      activesupport (= 3.0.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0.0)
      railties (= 3.0.1)
    railties (3.0.1)
      actionpack (= 3.0.1)
      activesupport (= 3.0.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.0)
    rake (0.8.7)
    thor (0.14.3)
    treetop (1.4.8)
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.23)

PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  mysql
  rails (= 3.0.1)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like a permissions problem. Presumably your web server is running as one user but your code is owned by another. So, check the permissions on every directory from the root all the way down to `en.yml` and make sure the directories are readable by the web server user, then check that `en.yml` can be read by the web server user.

Comment: And I haven't enough repu to up your answer, but thanx anyhow m8!